# Hostname is not displayed appropriately on command prompt & syslog messages

Tags: linux, command-line, hostname, syslog

I try to set my hostname as 0.6.0.07252014 but when i see on command prompt and syslog messages, it is not getting displayed appropriately.

Entered hostname: 0.6.0.07252014

Command prompt output: `root@0~$`

Expected Output: root@0.6.0.07252014~$

hostname file:

```
cat /etc/hostname
0.6.0.07252014
```

syslog file:

```
cat /var/log/messages:
Jul 28 15:55:27 0 user.info ...
```

Expected Output: `Jul 28 15:55:27 0.6.0.07252014 user.info ...`

Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specifications for the hostname state that it can comprise of A-Za-z0-9 and dashes.

You have included a dot, which is being interpreted as a domain separater, which is why you are only getting the first zero.

Consider this:

What is the difference between host `0.0` on domain `hello.com` and host `0` on domain `0.hello.com`?

If dots were allowed in the hostname, then it would be impossible to determine what part of the FQDN was hostname and what part was domain name.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_host_names

Comment: As a patch, I found solution like, Set PS1 environment variable with '\H' in place of '\h' and restart syslog daemon. But i will not prefer this way and try to remove this feature or try to change format of my software version.